# Multiple sets of seams for multiple UVs?

Tags: uv

When UV mapping and lightmapping an asset for game use, I find that I need to erase my seams after UV mapping in order to place new seams for the lightmapping. Is there anyway to preserve them, or use two different sets?

Comment: Why do you need multiple sets of seams?

Comment: In case I need to make adjustments to the UV map later.

Comment: @Denis One for regular textures, one for lightmaps. One for material alignment, one for blendmaps. One for handcrafted normalmaps, one for diffuse maps. Tons of possibilities by unwrapping a model in different manners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mark your seams, unwrap to one UV map:
[image: A cube with a set of seams, and the UV map for the seams. The first UV map is select in the UV Maps menu.]
Then create a new UV map, clear your seams, designate new seams, and unwrap to the new UV map:
[image: A cube with a different set of seams, and the UV map for the new seams. A second UV map is selected in the UV Maps menu.]
Then select the first UV map, and use UV/"Seams from Islands" which will re-designate seams based on the first UV map, restoring the seams that you had before.
[image: The UV menu open with the "Seams from Islands" option selected. The first UV map in the UV Map menu is selected. The cube in the background has the first set of seams from the first UV map selected.]

Comment: @KoolMode Holy crap... it took me 4 days to get that! Man! Well done! That's the best pun I've heard in years! :D